# Can't process ajax call on my page because Django request.is_ajax returns True when page is intially loaded

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I have a page that makes ajax calls, and my view checks if the call is ajax with .is_ajax function. However, when the page is initially loaded (for example if I stop running the server and then restart it) the is_ajax function seems to return True, which causes a MultiValueDictKeyError at /alltext, because the request does not contain the key "alltext", which contains the data from my other ajax call.

The page is a e-commerce product page, and the product has different variants (i.e. size and color), and when the user chooses variants from a dropdown menu (i.e. Large, Blue), it makes an ajax call to the backend to retrieve the price of this specific variant from the database.

Here is my code:

**views.py**

```
def product_info(request):
if request.method == "GET" and not request.is_ajax: # this is supposed to be loaded on page load
    return render(request, "product_info.html")

elif request.is_ajax and request.method == "GET":

    print(request.is_ajax)

    '''When a user chooses a product variant on the page, this makes an ajax call
    to retrieve the price of this combination'''

    print("request was ajax")

    combinations = request.GET["alltext"]
    combinations_list = combinations.split(";")
    product = Product.objects.all().latest("id")

    var_names = Variation.objects.filter(product=product)

    corresponding_values = []
    for i in range(len(combinations_list)):
        # finding this variant in database

        var_name = var_names[i]
        var_values = VariationValue.objects.filter(variation_name=var_name)
        for val_obj in var_values:
            val = val_obj.value
            if val == combinations_list[i]:
                corresponding_values.append(val_obj)

    found_price = None
    for i in range(len(corresponding_values)):
        val = corresponding_values[i]
        if i == 0:
            combo_query = VariationCombination.objects.filter(variation_value=val)
        else:
            combo_query = combo_query.filter(variation_value=val)

    price = combo_query[0].price

    return HttpResponse("You chose: " + combinations + "price: " + price)
```

And here is the relevant part of the product_info page - the forms where the user chooses the variants and the script that sends the variants to the backend:

**product_info.html**

```
    <form class="variations-form">
 {% for name in variation_names %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="btn-label">{{ name.variation_name }}:</label>
      <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
         <span class="selection"></span><span class="caret"></span>
      </button>-->

      <select name="variation{{ forloop.counter }}" class="form-control variations" id="variation{{ forloop.counter }}">
        <option value="" selected disabled>{{ name.variation_name }}</option>
      {% for key, value_list in variation_values.items %}
        {% if key == name.variation_name %}
         {% for value in value_list %}

          <option value="{{ value }}">{{ value }}</option>

          {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </select>


    </div>
    <br>
    {% endfor %}
 </form>
```

**Script tag with ajax call**

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

  $('.form-control').change(function(){
    if ($('#variation1').val()) {
      var valueFrom = $('.variations option:selected').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    var alltext = valueFrom.join(";")

        $('#chosen-options').html(alltext).show('fast');


          $.ajax(
    {
        type:"GET",
        data:{
                 'action':'options_chosen',
                 alltext: alltext
        },
        success: function( data )
        {
            $('#chosen-options').html(data).show('fast');
        }
     });
    };
  });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Still not entirely sure what was wrong but I fixed it! At first, the page was setup so that it loads the template "homepage.html" at first, and then when you click on a product it opens in the same page, by loading the template "product_info.html". So I just changed it so that the product_info opens up on a new page when you click a product (and added the new page to urls.py), and now it works!